# How can I reset settings for Internet Explorer using a script?

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, batch-file

I'm looking to reset Internet Explorer back to factory defaults using a batch file.
I'd also like to delete: all Downloads, History, Cookies and Cache, plus anything else in a user's IE profile.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Powershell script to do this. You will need to tweak it for your environment/needs though.  As it stands it requires human interaction. It was found on [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/329309/how-to-reset-ie9) & was created by [Aman Dhally](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-Internet-Explorer-20f838e7).

```
#+-------------------------------------------------------------------+   
#| = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = |   
#|{>/-------------------------------------------------------------\<}|            
#|: | Author:  Aman Dhally                                        | :|            
#| :| Email:   amandhally@gmail.com 
#|: | Purpose: Reset Internet Explorer Setting to Default   
#| :|       
#|: |  more info: http://newdelhipowershellusergroup.blogspot.in/                                                           
#| :|           
#|: |                 Date: 23 - July - 2012 
#|: |                            16:29 
#| :|     /^(o.o)^\    Version: 1                                    |: |  
#|{>\-------------------------------------------------------------/<}| 
#| = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = : = | 
#+-------------------------------------------------------------------+ 


## Load Assembly ## 
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load("System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089") 
#-  

"`n" 
Write-Host  "  ============================================" -ForegroundColor 'Green' 
Write-Host  "   [ Resetting IE To Default Settings]" -ForegroundColor 'Red'  
Write-Host  "  ============================================" -ForegroundColor 'Green' 
"`n" 
###  
"`n" 

$arrOfficeProcs = "iexplore" 
$continue = $false 
cls 

#Check for open Office apps 
do { 
    $arrRunning = @() 

    foreach ($proc in $arrofficeProcs) { 
        if(((get-process $proc -ea SilentlyContinue) -ne $Null)){ $arrRunning += $proc }        
    } 

    if ($arrRunning.length -gt 0 ) {   
        $d = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show( 
        "There are currently one or more Internet Explorer windows Open.`n`nYou must close down all Internet explorer windows before reset it to default.",  
        "Reset IE Settings to Default...",  
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::RetryCancel,  
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning ) 

        if ($d -eq [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel) { exit } 

    } else {  
        $continue = $true 
        write-host "  No IE process are currently running"  -ForegroundColor 'Green' 
        "`n" 
        Write-Host "  Please TICK on `"Delete personal Settings`" and then click on `"Reset`" button   <====" -ForegroundColor 'Yellow'  
        "`n" 
        & RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults | Out-Null 
        "`n" 
        Write-Host "  ====> Please Launch Internet Explorer Now" -ForegroundColor 'Magenta'  


"`n" 
Write-Host  "  ============================================" -ForegroundColor 'Green' 
Write-Host  "   [ Resetting Done]" -ForegroundColor 'Red'  
Write-Host  "  ============================================" -ForegroundColor 'Green' 
"`n" 


    } 


} while ( $continue -eq $false ) 


#### End of the Script #### A m a n     D h a l l y ---- amandhally@gmail.com
```

Answer (score -2):

To reset Internet Explorer automatically, follow these steps:

Note: This Microsoft Fix it is supported by Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP.

1. Download: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9646978
2. In the File Download dialog box, click Run, and then follow the
   steps in the wizard.
3. In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog
   box, click Reset.

   Click to select the Delete personal settings check box if you also
   want to remove browsing history, search providers, Accelerators,
   home pages, Tracking Protection, and ActiveX Filtering data.
4. When Internet Explorer finishes applying the default settings, click
   Close, and then click Close again.
5. Close and then start Internet    Explorer.

Comment: yes mr thankx for ur replay .... but i looking for automatically reset each time when i logon in  my pc ..... then i need batch file do that automatically .... i but this batch inside start-up folder or schedule tasks to execute it directly after each start windows